# Mapping Expressions in Linq

Tags: .net, linq

I am playing around with mapping Linq Queries on my business objects to my Entity Framework database.  Has anybody else gone down this road - or more to the point, is there a better way to go about this.

What I want to accomplish is to be able to run simple queries against my business layer from my UI layer without having to add additional methods to the manager (BL Layer) or the Repository (DA Layer)

The benefit I have derived is I can describe the projection I want in the UI Layer, and don't need to create a seperate class, or a special method in my manager, or do extra coding in my DA layer to effeciently execute the query (in this case a key + aggregate data)

```
var promoSource = new Queryable<BL.Promo>(new PromoQueryProvider());//When executed, Maps a BL Promo code query to an EF.PromoCode query
var query = from x in promoSource
  where x.PromoCode != null && x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate
  group x by x.PromoCode
  into result
  select new
  {
    PromoCode = result.Key.Trim(),
    AverageOrderValue = result.Average(x => x.OrderSubtotal),
    NumberOfOrders = result.Count()
  };
var results = query.ToList(); //Executes the query in the data layer and passes back the projected data
promosDataView.DataSource = results;
promosDataView.DataBind();
```

where previously I would need to add a class to represent the view object, a method in the Manager to either construct the summary data from entities, **or** forward the call to the data layer to fetch the data from the database.

It seems to be working fine, in limited cases, but I also feel like I'm missing the boat in terms proper seperation - Am I going overkill in maintaning seperating layers for simple reporting scenarios in an ecommerce application?  Wouldn't I get the same benefit if i just used an EF Datasource on the aspx page?

Comment: Voted to migrate this to StackOverflow.

Comment: What does PromoQueryProvider does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I have started to go down this road with some initial success. For me, the key was transforming parts of the expressions that referenced `A.MemberOfA` to expressions that reference `B.MemberOfB`. For example, say you have a business object `A`:

```
class A { public bool Selected { get; set; } }
```

and a data object (entity) `B`:

```
class B { public int SelectedInd { get; set; } }
```

As you can see, in the database, the selected state of `B` is defined by an indicator `int`. If you want to get all the selected `A`s, you might have a predicate:

```
Expression<Func<A, bool>> aPredicate = a => a.Selected;
```

Now you need to execute that predicate on your entity set. Maybe your business rule is a `B` is selected if `SelectedInd > 0`:

```
Expression<Func<B, bool>> bPredicate = b => b.SelectedInd > 0;
```

For me, the trick was the [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) class. By extending this class and overriding the `Visit` method, you can replace the parts that reference `A` and `A.Selected` with references to `B` and `B.SelectedInd > 0`:

```
class ExpressionTranslator : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression<Func<B, bool>> TranslatePredicate(Expression<Func<A, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<B, bool>>)this.Visit(predicate);
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp is Expression<Func<A, bool>>)
        {
            Expression<Func<A, bool>> predicate = (Expression<Func<A, bool>>)exp;
            Expression body = this.Visit(predicate.Body);
            ParameterExpression parameter = (ParameterExpression)this.Visit(predicate.Parameters[0]);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<B, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }
        else if (exp is ParameterExpression)
        {
            ParameterExpression param = (ParameterExpression)exp;
            if (param.Type == typeof(A))
                return bPredicate.Parameters[0];
        }
        else if (exp is MemberExpression)
        {
            MemberExpression mbrExpr = (MemberExpression)exp;
            if (mbrExpr.Member == typeof(A).GetProperty("Selected"))
                return this.Visit(bPredicate.Body);
        }
        else
            return base.Visit(exp);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can imagine making this logic more generic. In my own implementation, I register objects mapping selectors so that `ExpressionTranslator.Visit` dynamically selects the expressions to return based on `exp`.

Hope this helps.